# Reading .pgn files to display statistics about Chess games

Tags: c++, game, c++11, parsing

I am currently writing my first actual C++ project. I like Chess and I would like to see how good I'm doing on a monthly basis, so the idea is to read the log files (.pgn files) from the games and tell me how many games I won and such.

My question specially relates to Games.cpp where I'm not sure I have done the right thing in having both a `getMonths()` returning a list of all the months I have played a game and a `getGamesByMonth(std::string month)` returning all the games played on a given month. Seems like too much work - maybe a simpler solution is available.

Also, looking at `wonAsBlack()`, `wonAsWhite()`, `lostAsWhite()`, etc, seems like too much work as well - there might be a better solution to this as well. You can see the actual way it works in main.cpp where I have made a test case.

The code is [here](https://github.com/madsravn/PGNHelper).

**Games.cpp:**

```
#include "Games.hpp"
#include "Parser.hpp"

Games::Games() {

}

Games::Games(std::vector<Game> games) {
    pgames = games;
}

void
Games::openFile(std::string tfile) {
    Parser parser;
    parser.parse(tfile);
    pgames = parser.games();
}

size_t
Games::getSize() {
    return pgames.size();
}

Games
Games::getGamesWonBy(std::string winner) {
    std::vector<Game> games;
    for(Game &game : pgames) {
        if(game.getWinner().find(winner) == 0) {
            games.push_back(game);
        }
    }
    return games;
}

Games
Games::getGamesLostBy(std::string loser) {
    std::vector<Game> games;
    for(auto &game : pgames) {
        if(game.getLoser().find(loser) == 0) {
            games.push_back(game);
        }
    }
    return games;
}

std::vector<std::string>
Games::getMonths() {
    std::vector<std::string> months;
    for(Game &game : pgames) {
        std::string month = game.getMonth();
        auto index = std::find(months.begin(), months.end(), month);
        if(index == months.end()) {
            months.push_back(month);
        }
    }
    return months;
}

Games
Games::getGamesByMonth(std::string month) {
    std::vector<Game> games;
    for(auto &game : pgames) {
        if(game.getMonth() == month) {
            games.push_back(game);
        }
    }
    Games rgames(games);
    return rgames;
}

Games
Games::getDrawGames() {
    std::vector<Game> games;
    for(auto &game : pgames) {
        if(game.getDraw() == true) {
            games.push_back(game);
        }
    }
    Games rgames(games);
    return rgames;
}

Games
Games::getGamesByType(std::string type) {
    std::vector<Game> games;
    for(auto &game : pgames) {
        if(game.getType() == type) {
            games.push_back(game);
        }
    }
    Games rgames(games);
    return rgames;
}

Games
Games::wonAsBlack() {
    std::vector<Game> games;
    for(auto &game : pgames) {
        if(game.getResult() == "0-1") {
            games.push_back(game);
        }
    }
    Games rgames(games);
    return rgames;
}

Games
Games::wonAsWhite() {
    std::vector<Game> games;
    for(auto &game : pgames) {
        if(game.getResult() == "1-0") {
            games.push_back(game);
        }
    }
    Games rgames(games);
    return rgames;
}

Games
Games::lostAsBlack() {
    return wonAsWhite();
}

Games
Games::lostAsWhite() {
    return wonAsBlack();
}

Games
Games::drawAsWhite(std::string name) {
    std::vector<Game> games;
    for(auto &game : pgames) {
        if(game.getWhite().find(name) == 0  && game.getResult() == "½-½") {
            games.push_back(game);
        }
    }
    return games;
}

Games
Games::drawAsBlack(std::string name) {
    std::vector<Game> games;
    for(auto &game : pgames) {
        if(game.getBlack().find(name) == 0 && game.getResult() == "½-½") {
            games.push_back(game);
            }
    }
    return games;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "Game.hpp"
#include "Parser.hpp"
#include "Games.hpp"
int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    bool STRtags = false; 
    std::string line;
    //Parser parser;
    if(argc > 1) {
        // Open argument as file
        //parser.parse(std::string(argv[1]));

        //games = parser.games();
        Games games;
        games.openFile(std::string(argv[1]));
        games = games.getGamesByType("15|10");
        auto months = games.getMonths();
        for(auto &month : months) {
            std::cout << "Stats for " << month << std::endl;
            Games thismonth = games.getGamesByMonth(month);
            Games wonbyme = thismonth.getGamesWonBy("madsravn");
            Games drawGames = thismonth.getDrawGames();
            Games lostbyme = thismonth.getGamesLostBy("madsravn");
            std::cout << "Amount of games: " << thismonth.getSize() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Won: " << wonbyme.getSize() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "==> As white: " << wonbyme.wonAsWhite().getSize() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "==> As black: " << wonbyme.wonAsBlack().getSize() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Lost: " << lostbyme.getSize() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "==> As white: " << lostbyme.lostAsWhite().getSize() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "==> As black: " << lostbyme.lostAsBlack().getSize() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Draw: " << drawGames.getSize() << std::endl; 
            std::cout << "==> As white: " << drawGames.drawAsWhite("madsravn").getSize() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "==> As black: " << drawGames.drawAsBlack("madsravn").getSize() << std::endl << std::endl;

        }
    } else {
        std::cout << "Takes one argument, the file which needs to be parsed." << std::endl; 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Games.hpp**

```
#ifndef GAMES_HPP_
#define GAMES_HPP_
#include "Game.hpp"
class Games {
    public:
        Games();
        Games(std::vector<Game> games);
        void openFile(std::string tfile);
        size_t getSize();
        Games getGamesWonBy(std::string winner);
        Games getGamesLostBy(std::string loser);
        std::vector<std::string> getMonths();
        Games getGamesByMonth(std::string month);
        Games getDrawGames();
        Games getGamesByType(std::string type);
        Games wonAsBlack();
        Games wonAsWhite();
        Games lostAsWhite();
        Games lostAsBlack();
        Games drawAsWhite(std::string name);
        Games drawAsBlack(std::string name);
    private:
        std::vector<Game> pgames;

};

#endif
```

Answer (score 4):

**Games.cpp**

- It's not necessary to have member functions access `private` data members by their getters.  These particular functions already have full access to the class.
- Too many of your member functions begin with `get`, yet they don't all perform simple member-accessing.  This is a sign that your functions need to be renamed to accurately identify their purpose.  Consider this function of yours:

  ```
  if (game.getDraw() == true) {}
  ```

  Unless `draw` is a `bool`, this could be misleading.  Make it clear that it's supposed to perform a Boolean operation.
- `if (game.getDraw() == true) {}` can simply be `if (game.getDraw()) {}`.
- I'd recommend making `std::vector<Game>` a `typedef` (under `private`).
- This:

  ```
  Games::Games(std::vector<Game> games) {
      pgames = games;
  }
  ```

  should be an initializer list instead:

  ```
  Games::Games(std::vector<Game> games) : pgames(games) {}
  ```
- `getSize()` should instead be defined in the class header (also as `const`):

  ```
  std::size_t Games::getSize() const {return pgames.size();}
  ```
- When a non-native type (such as `std::string`) parameter will not be modified, have it passed by const-reference:

  ```
  Games::getGamesWonBy(std::string const& winner) {}
  ```
- If these are supposed to be conditionals (kinda hard to tell for sure):

  ```
  if (game.getWinner().find(winner) == 0) {}
  if (game.getLoser().find(loser) == 0) {}
  ```

  make it clear that they are (`false` in this case):

  ```
  if (!game.getWinner().find(winner)) {}
  if (!game.getLoser().find(loser)) {}
  ```

**Main.cpp**

- It'd be a good idea to alphabetize your `#include <...>`s for organization.
- Unless you're okay with flushing the stream with each `endl`, use `\n` in the `cout`s instead.
- I'd suggest grouping these lines appropriately based on their roles for readability (especially the outputs).  This is important because you need to make sure your driver code is written as intended, as this is what tests your class.
- It appears that `line` isn't used anywhere.  If it's a leftover, then get rid of it.  This is a reason why variables should always declared near the line(s) where they are used.
- The very last output seems out of place when preceded by that huge block of outputs.  You could instead test for a failed condition first.  If it does fail, display that message *and `return EXIT_FAILURE`* (or 1).  If it doesn't fail, run the program and then terminate with the `return 0`.

Comment: Thanks! But I'm a little unsure what you mean about the last comment you made. Why would I make a if(!game.getWinner().find(winner)) ? I just need to check if the winner is the string I pass

Comment: @Mads: With all that accessing, it's hard to tell exactly what value this is supposed to return.  In general, 0 is equal to `false` when dealing with `bool`s.  If that's *not* what's being tested here, then I'll correct this.

Comment: *If you don't need the default constructor, just leave it out. The compiler will make one for you.* He has defined a non-default constructor as well, and then the compiler will *not* define a default one. So, he does need it.

Answer (score 4):

Most of your member functions could (and IMO, should) be rewritten to use standard algorithms, such as:

```
Games
Games::getGamesLostBy(std::string loser) {
    std::vector<Game> games;
    for(auto &game : pgames) {
        if(game.getLoser().find(loser) == 0) {
            games.push_back(game);
        }
    }
    return games;
}
```

...would be better (IMO) as:

```
Games
Games::getGamesLostBy(std::string const &loser) { 
    std::vector<Game> games;

    std::copy_if(pgames.begin(), pgames.end(),
                 std::back_inserter(games),
                 [&](game const &g) { return g.getLoser().find(loser)==0; });
    return games;
}
```

Likewise, `Games::wonAsWhite()` would be better as:

```
Games
Games::wonAsWhite() {
    std::vector<Game> games;
    std::copy_if(pgames.begin(), pgames.end(),
                 std::back_inserter(games),
                 [](Game const &g) { return g.getResult() == "1-0";});
    return games;
}
```

I'd also note that most of `Games`'s member functions are really pretty much alike -- producing some subset of the games in the `Games`. Given the number, I think it might be worth considering writing a `filtered_iterator` (or something similar) that would take a condition like one of the above lambdas, and iterate over the  items in the collection that meet the specified condition. Alternatively, you might want to consider using a Boost [filter_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/iterator/doc/filter_iterator.html) that already provides this capability packaged, portable and tested.